# How can I get a list of available methods in a WebAPI web service?

Tags: c#, httpclient

I'm building a small test tool that should provide the user a list of web services (built using WebAPI). The user should be able to choose a service to test.
I'm using

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://'localhost':51062/");

// Add an Accept header for JSON format.

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

and am looking for something like

```
client.GetAllWebServices()
```

which would return a list of methods that the user can see. Meaning, the methods that he developed on the controller and wants to test.

Comment: Check [ApiExplorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2012/06/15/using-apiexplorer-to-export-api-information-to-postman-a-chrome-extension-for-testing-web-apis.aspx), it might get you going.

Comment: That gives me these:
-  methodInfos {System.Reflection.MethodInfo[43]} System.Reflection.MethodInfo[]
+  [0] {System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpRequestHeaders get_DefaultRequestHeaders()} System.Reflection.MethodInfo 
+  [1] {System.Uri get_BaseAddress()} 
+  [2] {Void set_BaseAddress(System.Uri)} 
+  [3] {System.TimeSpan get_Timeout()}  
etc...
It doesn't provide the methods that the developer wrote, such as "GetAllCustomers()"

Comment: It seems that Kobi is right when saying it "doesn't "know" anything about your specific API URLs". Perhaps I should use something else instead of HTTPClient?

Comment: Is there any example to use it for some general REST api?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Michael was correct to mention [`ApiExplorer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.description.apiexplorer(v=vs.118).aspx). This gives you details of all the WebApi methods for you. You just need to format it how you want the response.

Here is a simple example to get a list of all the methods with their parameters and return types. You can of course make this much more comprehensive - just browse the objects to find what you need:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class ApiMethodController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<HelpMethod> GetMethods()
        {
            // get the IApiExplorer registered automatically
            IApiExplorer ex = this.Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer();

            // loop, convert and return all descriptions 
            return ex.ApiDescriptions
                // ignore self
                .Where(d => d.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName != "ApiMethod")
                .Select(d =>
                {
                    // convert to a serializable structure
                    return new HelpMethod
                    {
                        Parameters = d.ParameterDescriptions.Select(p => new HelpParameter
                        {
                            Name = p.Name,
                            Type = p.ParameterDescriptor.ParameterType.FullName,
                            IsOptional = p.ParameterDescriptor.IsOptional
                        }).ToArray(),
                        Method = d.HttpMethod.ToString(),
                        RelativePath = d.RelativePath,
                        ReturnType = d.ResponseDescription.DeclaredType == null ?
                            null : d.ResponseDescription.DeclaredType.ToString()
                    };
                });
        }
    }

    public class HelpMethod
    {
        public string Method { get; set; }
        public string RelativePath { get; set; }
        public string ReturnType { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<HelpParameter> Parameters { get; set; }
    }

    public class HelpParameter
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public bool IsOptional { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The nice thing is that it is a WebApi call itself, so you can use the `HttpClient` to call and process it using http://www.localhost.com/api/ApiMethod/Methods. Here's a sample JSON response:

```
[
    {
        "Method": "GET",
        "RelativePath": "api/Account/{id}",
        "ReturnType": "WebApplication1.Models.Account",
        "Parameters": [
            {
                "Name": "id",
                "Type": "System.Int32",
                "IsOptional": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Method": "POST",
        "RelativePath": "api/Account",
        "ReturnType": null,
        "Parameters": [
            {
                "Name": "a",
                "Type": "WebApplication1.Models.Account",
                "IsOptional": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Method": "GET",
        "RelativePath": "api/Maths?i={i}&j={j}",
        "ReturnType": "System.Int32",
        "Parameters": [
            {
                "Name": "i",
                "Type": "System.Int32",
                "IsOptional": false
            },
            {
                "Name": "j",
                "Type": "System.Int32",
                "IsOptional": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Going Forward**

Getting XML doc comments out isn't so clear cut, but there is a tutorial on [MSDN Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2012/12/10/asp-net-web-api-help-page-part-3-advanced-help-page-customizations.aspx).

Also, there are other packages available which you can use, hook into, steal from, which do similar to what you need, for example

- [Swagger.Net](https://github.com/Swagger-Net/Swagger.Net)
- [RAML](http://raml.org/)

More details on these [in VS Mag](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/09/01/web-api-documentation-tools.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Rhumborl!
there was no d.ResponseDescription, but I don't need it.
And this is a little extra work than I was expecting, since this extra controller needs to be created, but it's deffinetly better than nothing, and it works! Thanks again!