# Web app Get list of Available methods via swagger?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger

Currently I have setup an Azure WebAPI using the default template in visual studio 2017.

The template includes Swagger and Swashbuckle.  I have enabled swagger and can navigate to /swagger in my hosted WebAPI to see the list of available methods.

I also have a Web App mvc5 that will consume the Web API.

What i would like to do is first get a list of available web api methods including there params.

So far i see one post on stack [web api get methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267775/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-available-methods-in-a-webapi-web-service)

This explains using the APIExplorer library to get what i need.  I was hopping to use swagger somehow,  Is this possible? How would one use swagger to get a list of available methods and params, then store in a list of objects.

My app enables swagger UI, I have not set anything else up involving swagger as of yet.

```
 })
   .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
 {
```

I was wondering is there some sort of method i can call to get this list from swagger?