# List all method in Rest API web service

Tags: c#, rest

Is it possible to get list of all methods available to consumer of Rest API client?
I tried with OPTION but it gives only PUT DELETE answer not methods in webservice
and [How can I get a list of available methods in a WebAPI web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267775/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-available-methods-in-a-webapi-web-service), but I couldn't find example to use that for some random REST api.

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short version: No.

There is no way for a client to know which "methods" (*resources* or *urls* actually) are available on a given server / random REST API. This information *could* be published using one of various ways - POSH, swagger, postman-collection etc, in which case the client could be modified to use this information.